# fell only a few goals short of

Tags: idiom-requests

Goddard, an adventurer, explorer and lecturer who evidently **fell only a few goals short of** a boyhood list that numbered more than 100, died Friday at a Glendale hospital of complications from cancer, said his son Jeffery.

---

In this sentence, why is not 'fell short of only a few goals ' but 'fell only a few goals short of'?

I think 'fall short of' is an idiom. If it is not an idiom, is 'only a few goals' a object of 'fell'?

Plz analyze this sentence in detail.
thank you.

Comment: The phrase is “a few * short of a”, e.g. a few days short of (meaning less than) a year.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct.  Goddard almost completed his list: he fell short of it by only a few goals.  (Apparently as a boy he made a long list of goals, and fulfilled nearly all of them.)

*only a few goals* is not an object of *fell*, it's more like a measurement.  “I missed the target by a few inches”: the object is *target*, not *inches*.  The sentence in question has no formal object, unless we consider *list* to be the object of *fell short of*.

Your alternative, *fell short of only a few goals*, is not wrong, but implies that each of his goals was a number (rather than a singular accomplishment).